# Are multiples of representable homology classes still representable by smooth submanifolds?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

Recently the following question comes up in my research. Suppose we have a closed compact connected smooth manifold $M,$ of dimension $d+c$ and an integral homology class $[N]$ induced by a compact closed smoothly embedded orientable submanifold $N$ of dimension $d.$ For $d\ge 3,c\ge 3,$ is it true that any multiples of $[N],$ i.e., $n[N]$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ still contains a smoothly embedded orientable representative? Or can one find counterexamples?

(The motivation comes from geometric measure theory, in which embedded submanifolds counted with multiplicities cannot be distinguished by analytical means from embeddings. Thus, it is sometimes advantageous to know a priori if the multiplicities can be destroyed. )

I'm aware of Thom's results for low codimensions and low dimensions. However, I don't know much algebraic topology to see if this is a trivial question.  I also know what to do when transversality does the job for $d<c.$ Thus, you can say it's mainly about the case $d\ge c$